# jQuery-ui draggable dragging event is not triggered when helper is dragged outside an iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

https://www.facebook.com/anuary/app_295048007277420 "Watch Trailer & Clips" is the helper for the draggable object.

If mouse cursor moves (while dragging) outside of the iframe, the event is no longer being updated.

It works perfectly fine in an iframe-less environment, https://dev.anuary.com/c5e22f1a-e772-5ad6-afff-9202af28e644/.

Is there a setting that can fix this behaviour? I suspect that jQuery-ui mouse movement event is binded to `document` rather than the `window`, which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using document mouse move and mouse up events inside iframe mouse down like below.

```
element.bind('mousedown.' + this.widgetName, function(event){
                        _mouseMoveDelegate = function(e){
                            return _mouseMove();
                        };
                        _mouseUpDelegate = function(e){
                            return _mouseUp();
                        };
                      $(document).bind('mousemove.' + this.widgetName, _mouseMoveDelegate).bind('mouseup.' + this.widgetName, _mouseUpDelegate);
});
```